# Magento2.4.2 - After Installing Fresh Instance All Pages Messy

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I have tried to install `Magento2.4.2` in both way.

1. Using `Composer` & 2. Downloading `.zip`

Both time I have found `root` **index.php** file is missing. After adding from `Magento2.4.1` in console getting error

[image]

From very first view we can see the path becomes wrong.

**In correct Path** : `http://127.0.0.1/magento242/static/version1613139426/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg`

**Correct Path** : `http://127.0.0.1/magento242/pub/static/version1613139426/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg`

Anyone face the same issue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The magento instance is trying to use the pub directory as the web root instead of your magento root directory. You need to resolve the configuration conflict, either by altering your web root in the server configuration to be the pub directory or changing the magento configuration to run from the magento directory rather the pub directory.

Comment: Can you please share where I have to change this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue with magento 2.4.2 on my localhost xampp setup, I also tried toggle 'document_root_is_pub'=>true option given in app/etc/env.php to false but didn't resolve, will keep looking and get back if i can find something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue upgrading from 2.2.9 to 2.4.2. The issue also appears on a fresh install of 2.4.2 open source.

Fixed this by issuing the following SQL statement

```
"insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);"

n98-magerun2.phar setup:upgrade; 
n98-magerun2.phar setup:di:compile; 
n98-magerun2.phar setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_AU -f
```